# Minimise DOM Elements in forEach (Node/Express)

Tags: node.js, express, dom, jquery-chosen

I have a Node/Express app and in my NEW routes, I have a dropdown field that allows one or more selections, using a forEach loop through all existing users in the database.  Currently there are 1400 users, though the figure is steadily increasing.

```
                            <label for="interviewees" class="profile-label">Your PANGYAO Username:</label>
                            <select id="interviewees" class="mselect standard-input" name="haoPangyao[interviewees][]" data-placeholder="Select Your Username" multiple>
                                <% interviewees.forEach(interviewee => { %>
                                    <option value="<%- interviewee.id %>"><%- interviewee.username %> </option>
                                <% }); %>
                            </select>
                        </div>
```

On what is otherwise a simple input form, Google Pagespeed is flagging this as an issue under, 'Avoid excessive DOM size', an issue which is only set to grow as the number of users increases.

I am using JS Chosen for the field; is there a way I can retain the ability to search for (multiple) users, but avoid loading the entire list each time as individual DOM elements?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to look at incorporating JS to lazy load the contents of this tool or provide a search fields and is JS to find the results against an API call.